# How to Install specific version of spark using specific version of scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, homebrew

I'm running spark 2.4.5 in my mac. When I execute `spark-submit --version`

```
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.5
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.12, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_242
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user centos on 2020-02-02T19:38:06Z
Revision cee4ecbb16917fa85f02c635925e2687400aa56b
Url https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/spark.git
Type --help for more information.
```

Note it's using scala version `2.11.12`. However, my app is using `2.12.8` and this is throwing me the well known `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V` error.

My question is how to make my spark `2.4.5` use scala `2.12` as indicated in their [official webiste](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/) under `Download` section: `Spark 2.4.5 uses Scala 2.12`

I tried `brew search apache-spark` and got

```
==> Formulae
apache-spark ✔
```

and `brew info apache-spark` returned me

```
apache-spark: stable 2.4.5, HEAD
Engine for large-scale data processing
https://spark.apache.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.4 (1,188 files, 250.7MB) *
  Built from source on 2020-02-03 at 14:57:17
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/apache-spark.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openjdk ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 7,150 (30 days), 15,180 (90 days), 64,459 (365 days)
install-on-request: 6,900 (30 days), 14,807 (90 days), 62,407 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Appreciate if any advice is given!

Comment: I don't know who vote down my question. If you think there is something to be improved, please kindly support your vote with a message.

Answer (score 1):

Spark community provides older versions of spark in this website, you can choose any version according your OS, For windows you can use **tgz** extension file.

https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/

Answer (score 0):

You can build any custom version of Spark locally.

- Clone https://github.com/apache/spark locally
- Update pom file, focusing on `scala.version`, `hadoop.version`, `scala.binary.version`, and `artifactId` in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml
- `mvn -DskipTests clean package` (from their README)
- After successful build, find all jars in `assembly/target/scala-2.11/jars`, `external/../target`, and other external jars you desire, which may be in `provided` scope of your jars submitted.
- Create a new directory and `export SPARK_HOME="/path/to/directory_name"` so that https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/spark-submit will detect it (see the source to see why)
- Copy the jars into $SPARK_HOME/jars and make sure there are no conflicting jars
- The bin/ scripts should be the same, but if needed, specifically reference those and possibly even unlink the brew ones if you no longer need them

Comment: Thank you, @Elinda. I think this solves local environment setup really nicely. Would you be able to extend this further from CI/CD perspective? I'm planning to deployment solution into an EC2 instance where spark would installed via command invoked by jeankin's pipeline.